# Message conversion in spring mvc application

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, httpresponse

Hi I have problem where I need to respond to a request that I receiving on my controller

Lets say

```
class Response{
 long id;
 String type
}

@Controller
class MyController{
@RequestMapping(value = "/getValue")
public Response getValue(){
 return Response;
}
}
```

The problem for me here is that My response type can be HTML or JSON, and default is JSON. By adding @RequestBody annotation I could able to convert the Response object to JSON.

But now I need the response to be converted to HTML or JSON based on the type in Response.

if (Response.type.equals("html")) return HTML content ( I have a jsp that can parse the response objecct)
else
return json response

I am new to Spring mvc and i cant use the path extension and params like format=json in my case. Because the content type is basically depends on the data that I am sending.

I am not getting any clue to have a single entry point and having multiple format types in this case. I really dont want multiple handlers in my controller.

Can somebody help me in this.

Comment: I couldn't get any way to use the message converting to html and json

Answer (score 0):

You have to read about org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.

Here goes an exemple:

```css
<bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
  <property name="order" value="1" />
  <property name="mediaTypes">
   <map>
    <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
    <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
   </map>
  </property>
  <property name="defaultViews">
   <list>
    <bean
     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
     <property name="marshaller" ref="Jaxb2Marshaller">
     </property>
    </bean>
   </list>
  </property>
  <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
 </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this, but I think the quickest way is probably to just return the View object you want for the Response.type value.

```
@Controller
class MyController{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getValue")
    public View getValue(){

       if(Response.type == "json")
          return new MappingJackson2JsonView();

       else if(Response.type == "xml")
         return MarhallingView();

       else
           return new InternalResourceView("/getValue.jsp");
    }
}
```

There are more elegant ways you can do this. For example you could configure multiple view resolvers and return the view names in your controller ie. "getValue.json", "getValue.xml", "getValue.jsp" then let the view resolver figure it out based on extension.

Another option is writing a custom view resolver to check the Response.type value and return the appropriate view. I haven't done that myself, so I don't have an example but it should be possible.

Comment: I am actually looking for the way with custom view resolver.. I don't want m my controller to return a view.. That will make my org more uglier..

Comment: I have many controllers... and having if conditions or switches in controller looks weird to me

Comment: There's nothing wrong with returning a view based on a conditional in your controller, that's the point of a controller. However if you do need this in multiple places then a custom view resolver is probably your best bet. I'm just not sure off hand how to get access to the model object from within a view resolver.